# How can I overlay the CustomPaint canvas directly overtop of a video player widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

This is what I have right now

[image: pic]

```
return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
              child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  foregroundPainter: MyPaint(),
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video

I need the CustomPaint canvas to be fixed over the top of the video widget, so it stays in the same place regardless of the window size.

Comment: Stack()  not working ?

Comment: Using stack just centers the canvas in the middle

Comment: `Stack` with `Positioned`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/3cff3fa5aba6de8bbed5be7008512ea4.png still clips outside the video

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement?

```dart
Stack(
 children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
       left: 0, // can be 100, 200 any number you want
       top: 0,
       child: [Your view]
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: That's what I have but the problem is the position https://i.gyazo.com/542928575aa2d2b195caa9afbba78a4b.png

I need to know the position of the video player at all times, regardless of the screen size & aspect ratio.

Comment: you should have way to know video size before get the video.  And you can know video size after video playing.   base on the video size(width & height),  you can setup your position.